# How to show parent and childrenwith ng-options

Tags: angularjs, json, ng-options

I want to create ng-options from with I can select elements from parent object and children objects.
My json looks like this:

```
{
"errors":[

],
"headquarters":{
  "id":1,
  "name":"headquarter name",
  "departments":[
     {
        "id":2,
        "name":"department A name",
        "divisions":[
           {
              "id":6,
              "name":"Division A name"
           },
           {
              "id":7,
              "name":"Division B name"
           },
           {
              "id":8,
              "name":"Division C name"
           }
        ]
     },
     {
        "id":3,
        "name":"department B name",
        "divisions":[
           {
              "id":11,
              "name":"Division E name"
           },
           {
              "id":12,
              "name":"Division F name"
           },
           {
              "id":13,
              "name":"Division G name"
           }
        ]
     }
  ]
 }
 }
```

From this Json I want to pick headquarters or department and then if department and not headquarters is selected use picked id to select division. I tried to do something like this:

```
      element.id as element.name for element in user.structure.headquarters && user.structure.headquarters.departments
```

But it's not working.

Is this possible to do?

Or is there any other way to do it?

There is always only one headquarters in the JSON.

Comment: so you want to pick a department first and then pick one of the divisions within it?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this to pick the department first and then get the divisions from the selected department

http://plnkr.co/edit/PTWxUHobi7agUlB9fCHv?p=preview

Your HTML would look something like this:

```
<select ng-model="selectedDept" 
        ng-options="dept.id as dept.name for dept in data.headquarters.departments"
        ng-change="getDivisions()"></select>


<select ng-if="selectedDept" 
        ng-model="selectedDivision" 
        ng-options="div.id as div.name for div in selectedDivisions"></select>
```

Comment: Yes that's almost what I want.But from this first select I want to have option to pick headquarters or department not just department.
And then if I picked department I want to pick division and If I picked headquarters then I dont need division.
I'm asking if I can make this first select let me pick from departments + headquarters

Comment: That doesnt make sense as they are not at the same level, the departments are inside the headquarters which is an object, you can have select only on arrays or collections but not when you have a single object

Comment: I see. So how shoud I proceed? I'm just learning javascript and angular and Ihave problems with finding good solutions for that kind of problems

Comment: If you have an array of headquarters, then you can just have one more select tag before the other two, then list all departments based on selected headquarter and then pick divisions from selected department